# Exit bash script when curl gets a non 200 HTTP status

Tags: bash, shell, script, shell-script, curl

I have a bash script setup to perform a few curl requests

```
for currency in EUR INR JPY
do
  curl -i --data '{"currency": "'$currency'"}' -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://0.0.0.0:8080/price && echo
done
```

Is there a way to make the script exit if one of the curl responses come back with an http status != 200?

I also want to keep the standard curl output, e.g I don't want a solution that only prints the http status code.

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

`--fail`, as mentioned in the `man` page, seems to do the job:

```
$ curl --fail --location http://google.com/nope
$ echo $?
22
```

Comment: From the manpage, `--fail` is not suitable for a couple of reasons: 1. `Fail  silently (no output at all)`, and 2. `This  method  is  not  fail-safe  and  there  are occasions where non-successful response codes will slip through`.

Comment: You might also want to check out `--fail-with-body`.